# Re-writing FeatureLayer to memory causes ArcGIS Pro to Crash

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, memory, arcgis-notebook

I am working with Jupyter notebooks in *ArcGIS Pro* and would like to write some Feature layers to memory to speed up my operation. Currently it is taking roughly 24 hours. I have to emphasize it is very important that they are written to memory as a **feature layer** and not a ***feature class***, otherwise my code will not run correctly. I have found that I can get my point feature layers written to memory using the code below. However rewriting the layer to memory such as in a loop causes *Pro* to crash.

```
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures('ServiceLocation', "memory/ServiceLocationCopy")
```

I have tried deleting the feature layer from memory before writing again and it still causes crashing. It is a hard crash without any errors given and just gives me the option to send a crash report. The code below will reliably cause my system to crash.

```
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures('ServiceLocation', "memory/ServiceLocationCopy")
arcpy.Delete_management("memory/ServiceLocationCopy") 
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures('ServiceLocation', "memory/ServiceLocationCopy")
```

Currently I am running ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2, due to company policies I am unable to make any updates to my system. ServiceLocation is a simple point feature layer with no z values. I am wondering if this operation will cause Pro to crash for other users and if there is another way to write feature layers to memory that will not cause crashes.

Comment: Your distinction between feature layers and feature classes seems out of place. A layer is the plotting manifestation of a feature class (which is just data). Both in-memory and disk-based feature classes exist outside of a layer, but a layer can't exist without a source. Tools which expect a layer will accept a feature class, because creating a "Miranda layer" is a trivial exercise.

Comment: @Vince the distinction is specific to my use case. Layers pass their selection when used to export features. Feature classes loose the selection and the entire extent is exported. Not sure why they are acting this way and it could be related to something else I am doing but I know the feature layers will behave as desired.

Comment: But the data ***has*** to be written to a feature class, and ***can't*** be written to a layer -- Layers are only pointers to data sources, not data sources themselves. Yes, they provide selection sets, and allow you to trim the column list, but they can only be read and written **through**, not read and written **to**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to [BUG-000138150](https://support.esri.com/en-us/bug/the-geoprocessing-tool-arcpylistfeatureclasses-does-not-bug-000138150)...I'm testing its resolution in 3.2 now.

Comment: Good info. I will test with the recommended resolutions. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting your answer. I was able to verify things this morning and am able to write a feature layer to memory now after reading the bug report and following their suggested work around of `arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.scratchGDB`. Much thanks.

Comment: cool, understood